# The measure of scatteredness of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for a measure of "scatteredness" of a graph. This measure should give a sense how vertices of the graph are far from each other. I can use the average distance between all vertices, however, I would like to prefer a graph where the distance between the vertices is comparable.

For example, let's image there is a graph with $x$ vertices and the average distance is $y$ because one of the vertices is far from $(x-1)$ vertices that are close to each other. And there is another graph with the same number of vertices and the same average distance, but vertices are scattered within comparable distances. I prefer the second graph.

The graph is defined by distances between vertices, I can calculate the distance between any vertices.

I am very sorry for naive definition, I am weak at math. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I assume that 'distance' here is the distance between points in a plane, not graph distance in terms of number of vertices on a path between endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the variance of the distances between edges

Comment: Shouldn't he look for standard deviation instead? (I know it's the square root of the variation)

Comment: Either is fine both provide a measure for "scatteredness "

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you are weak with math so this may be a bit too complex but there are metrics on graphs designed to measure their "density".  Roughly, in them the distance between two points is low if there are many ways to get from one to the other.  If you add up all the distances in the graph you can get a measure of "density".

You can take a look at [Resistance Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_distance) and [Conductance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_%28graph%29).  From the first Resistance Distance page:

```
The resistance distance between two vertices of a simple connected graph, G, is equal to the 
resistance between two equivalent points on an electrical network, constructed so as to 
correspond to G, with each edge being replaced by a 1 ohm resistance.
```